# Как добавить время привязанное к часовому поясу в google app script?

Tags: javascript, discord, google-apps-script, webhook

У меня есть следующий код.
Я могу привязать время в embed (ваше), но я хочу, чтобы в footer отображалось 2 времени в 2х часовых поясах.
Это возможно как то реализовать ?

```
  var POST_URL = "discord webhook";
function onSubmit(e) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var allResponses = form.getResponses();
    var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
    var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
    var items = [];
 
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
        var answer = response[i].getResponse();
        try {
            var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
        } catch (e) {
            var parts = answer;
        }
 
        if (answer == "") {
            continue;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                items.push({
                    "name": question,
                    "value": parts[j],
                    "inline": false
                });
            } else {
                items.push({
                    "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
                    "value": parts[j],
                    "inline": false
                });
            }
        }
    }

    var time = new Date();
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload": JSON.stringify({
            "content":
             mention = "New form",
            "embeds": [{
                "fields": items,
              "color": '1488897',
                "footer": {
                    "text": "Moscow: " + time.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU") + " " + time.toLocaleTimeString("ru-RU") + "\nNovosibirsk: " + time.toLocaleDateString("ru-RU") + " " + time.toLocaleTimeString("ru-RU")
                }
            }]
        })
    };
 
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
    form.deleteResponse( latestResponse.getId() );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно в google app script узнать время и пояс, обработать и отправить в футер.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var data = new Date();     
  var year =data.getFullYear();
  var month =data.getMonth(); 
  var day =data.getDate();
  var hour =data.getHours();
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();//"Europe/Moscow"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ time.toLocaleTimeString("ru-RU", {timeZone:''})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399465/how-to-get-list-of-all-timezones-in-javascript